# Probability of winning odd number of times

Tags: probability

Two chess players A & B has same level of expertise, both play a series of *n* games. The probability *i*th game ends in a draw is $$i/(i+1)$$ P is the probability that A wins odd number of games, then what is the value of P when n = 99. If possible derive a general formula for n.

I tried to use symmetry what both have same probability but could not reach to final solution.

Comment: So what did you come with when you tried?

Comment: If $P_n$ is the probability A wins an odd number of games from the first $n$ games, then you can express $P_n$ in terms of $P_{n-1}$ and you start from $P_0=0$

Comment: You could look at the values for small $n$; $P_n$ should  approach $\frac12$ so you might look at something like $\frac{1}{1-2P_n}$ to see if you can spot a pattern and then prove what you see is correct

Comment: but how to take care of probability of draw ?

Comment: Your symmetry assumption seems reasonable based on "same level of expertise"; I suspect that makes the probability of $A$ winning the $i$th game $\frac1{2(i+1)}$

Comment: Still not getting..

Comment: What is the probability of A having won an odd number of games after $1$ game? After $2$ games?  After $3$ games?